# Postfix not using SSL certificate?

Tags: postfix

I have set up my /etc/postfix/main.cf file with the following commands:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN.com/privkey.pem
```

but after restarting postfix it is still not using the certificates? What gives? I've checked every other config file in /etc/postfix/ but there are nothing that overwrites it.

The same certificate works great in LiteSpeed and Dovecot.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I fixed it myself.

I had to run:

```
postmap -F hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
```

..and then restart postfix and it works.

Comment: Hi I'm having the same problem here. 
Can you tell me what this command does? Since I don't see /etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map file exists